# How do you set boolean values with "yarn config"?

Tags: yarnpkg

The following should illustrate the problem: 
using `yarn config set strict-ssl false` will not have the desired result. Does anybody know how to set this to boolean false instead of string 'false'?

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
$ yarn config set strict-ssl true --global
success Set "strict-ssl" to true.

$ yarn config set strict-ssl false --global
success Set "strict-ssl" to "false".
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: despite of @DimaSan 's opinion, this answer is simple and useful. thank you

Answer (score 1):

For Yarn 2 or later, add this to yarnrc.yml file

```
enableStrictSsl: false
```